Объединение датафреймов по фиксированному ключу и диапазону
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно объединить в pandas датафреймы?
У нас есть таблицы, которые необходимо соединить: в первой таблице в качестве ключа указаны "тип объекта" и  "км расположения", во второй таблице ключи - "тип объекта" и диапазон участка км (начало, конец).
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'наименование объекта':['Объект 1','Объект 2','Объект 3','Объект 4', 'Объект 5','Объект 6'],
                'Тип объекта':['Тип 1', 'Тип 1','Тип 2','Тип 2','Тип 3','Тип 3'],
               'км расположения':[101,124,95,301,251,499]
               })

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Тип объекта':['Тип 1','Тип 1','Тип 2','Тип 2','Тип 3','Тип 3','Тип 3'],
                'Начало участка, км':[0,200,0,200,0,200,400],
               'Конец участка, км':[200,400,200,400,200,400,600],                
               'Описание':['описание 1','описание 2','описание 1','описание 2','описание 1','описание 2','описание 3']
               })

Хочу получить таблицу вида
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'наименование объекта':['Объект 1','Объект 2','Объект 3','Объект 4', 'Объект 5','Объект 6'],
                'Тип объекта':['Тип 1', 'Тип 1','Тип 2','Тип 2','Тип 3','Тип 3'],
               'км расположения':[101,124,95,301,251,499],
               'Описание':['описание 1','описание 1','описание 1','описание 2','описание 2','описание 3']
               })


import pandas as pd



df1 = pd.DataFrame({'наименование объекта':['Объект 1','Объект 2','Объект 3','Объект 4', 'Объект 5','Объект 6'],
                'Тип объекта':['Тип 1', 'Тип 1','Тип 2','Тип 2','Тип 3','Тип 3'],
               'км расположения':[101,124,95,301,251,499]
               })

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Тип объекта':['Тип 1','Тип 1','Тип 2','Тип 2','Тип 3','Тип 3','Тип 3'],
                'Начало участка, км':[0,200,0,200,0,200,400],
               'Конец участка, км':[200,400,200,400,200,400,600],
               'Описание':['описание 1','описание 2','описание 1','описание 2','описание 1','описание 2','описание 3']
               })

#собрать все в один  DF 
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='Тип объекта')

#выбрать только где расположение в диапазоне
df3 = df3[(df3['км расположения'] > df3['Начало участка, км']) &
    (df3['км расположения'] < df3['Конец участка, км'])]

df3 = df3.drop(columns=['Начало участка, км', 'Конец участка, км'])

print(df3.to_string(index=False))


наименование объекта Тип объекта  км расположения   Описание
            Объект 1       Тип 1              101 описание 1
            Объект 2       Тип 1              124 описание 1
            Объект 3       Тип 2               95 описание 1
            Объект 4       Тип 2              301 описание 2
            Объект 5       Тип 3              251 описание 2
            Объект 6       Тип 3              499 описание 3


О, хорошая идея, я что-то не догадался )

@CrazyElf Что будет если оба фрейма большие, ай яй. А еще не проверял, что будет если пустое значение.

А для больших фреймов вообще не надо бы Pandas использовать. Для больших данных нормальные БД надо использовать. Ну или Spark какой-нибудь.

вообще, есть метод .between(). а строки с пустыми значениями нужно заранее удалять

А в чём сложность? Если отрезки именно такие всегда, то просто разделить нацело на 200 - и получится id, по которому датафреймы можно соединить. Рабочий пример на ваших данных:
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data1 = """
наименование объекта    Тип объекта км расположения
Объект 1    Тип 1   101
Объект 2    Тип 1   124
Объект 3    Тип 2   95
Объект 4    Тип 2   301
Объект 5    Тип 3   251
Объект 6    Тип 3   499
"""

data2 = """
Тип объекта Начало участка, км  Конец участка, км   Описание объекта
Тип 1   0   200 описание 1
Тип 1   200 400 описание 2
Тип 2   0   200 описание 1
Тип 2   200 400 описание 2
Тип 3   0   200 описание 1
Тип 3   200 400 описание 2
Тип 3   400 600 описание 3
"""

df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data1), sep='\t')
df2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data2), sep='\t')
df1['id'] = df1['км расположения'] // 200
df2['id'] = df2['Начало участка, км'] // 200
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['Тип объекта', 'id'])
df3 = df3.drop(columns=['id','Начало участка, км', 'Конец участка, км'])

Результат в df3:
    наименование объекта    Тип объекта км расположения Описание объекта
0   Объект 1    Тип 1   101 описание 1
1   Объект 2    Тип 1   124 описание 1
2   Объект 3    Тип 2   95  описание 1
3   Объект 4    Тип 2   301 описание 2
4   Объект 5    Тип 3   251 описание 2
5   Объект 6    Тип 3   499 описание 3


прошу прощения, что ввел в заблуждение. Я сделал эти таблицы, чтобы было понятно, что с чем хочу склеить, в настоящих данных отрезки разной длины

@алексейалексеев Тогда другой ответ лучше должен подойти )
